# Factorize methods taking &Box<T> and &T as argument

Tags: rust, polymorphism, traits, trait-objects

I have a method that I need to call with a trait parameter (let's call it `Listener`). The reason is that sometimes I have previously stored this trait parameter into a parent structure so it is inside a `Box`, and sometimes not.

So I have the two methods :

- `fref<T>(t: &T) where T: Listener`
- `fbox(t: &Box<dyn Listener>)`

and I would like both of them to call `f(t: ??)`. For now I duplicated the code in `fref` and `fbox` which works but is not good. So I am looking for a signature of `f` that would make it callable from `fref` and `fbox` to factorize my code. I was hoping one of the traits implemented by `Box` would be equivalent to a `&` (or at least find a common ground somewhere).

I tried the following:

- Writing `f<T>(t: &T) where T: Listener` but then I can't call from  `fbox` (`Listener` is not implemented by `Box<dyn Listener>`).
- Then changing the call from within `fbox` to `f(&*t)` to unbox my `Box<Listener>` but since `t` is not `Size`d I can't.
- Writing `f<T>(t: &T) where T: std::borrow::Borrow<Listener>` but then I can't call from `fref` (`Borrow` is not implemented by `Listener`)
- Same with `AsRef<Listener>`
- Last attempt with `Deref` [playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b155a09c2440e7b4160c1ffdf5dee471):

```
trait Listener {}
struct Mouse {}
impl Listener for Mouse {}

fn fbox(t: &Box<Listener>) {
    f(t);
}

fn fref<T>(t: &T)
where
    T: Listener,
{
    f(t);
}

fn f<T>(_t: &T)
where
    T: std::ops::Deref<Target = Listener>,
{

}

fn create_listener() -> impl Listener {
    Mouse {}
}

fn main() {
    let mouse = create_listener();
    let box_mouse: Box<Listener> = Box::new(Mouse {});

    fref(&mouse);
    fbox(&box_mouse);
}
```

Comment: Both `&T` and `Box<T>` implement `Deref` with `Target = T`. Is that what you are after? It's a bit unclear because you didn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have slightly improved the [Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67fc2cbe2c9f4c8476219497a580da8c) example from @Stargateur

Comment: ok I added a mcve based on @Stargateur with the question naming and an attempt at Deref

Comment: It's because `Listener` is a trait. The box is actually a trait object `Box<dyn Listener>`, while the other is a regular type parameter.

Comment: I don't thank you can because in one you try to use a static dispatch function with a dynamic dispatch data. But I probably miss something

Comment: *`Listener` is not implemented by `Box<dyn Listener>`* — Why don't you implement it then?

Comment: @Shepmaster well for me this is the point of ```Deref``` implemented by ```Box```, but I guess the ```dyn``` prevents this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Listener` is a trait, so `Box<Listener>` is *really* a trait object, `Box<dyn Listener>` - it is unfortunate that the `dyn` keyword is currently optional. Both `Box<dyn Listener>` and `&Mouse` implement `Deref`, with an associated `Target` type that implements `Listener`. In the case of `&Mouse` the deref `Target` is `Mouse`, but in the case of `Box<dyn Listener>` it is an unknown object, `dyn Listener` of *unknown* size.

To capture all of that information, you can write `f` like this:

```
fn f<T, L>(_listener: &T)
where
    T: Deref<Target = L>,
    L: Listener + ?Sized
{
}
```

And call it from each function like this:

```
fn fbox(listener: &Box<dyn Listener>) {
    f(listener);
}

fn fref<L>(listener: &L)
where
    L: Listener
{
    f(&listener);
}
```

---

Another, perhaps simpler way of looking at this is to forgo the `Deref` constraint and just use normal references. Use `Box::as_ref` to turn a `Box` in to a reference in order to call it. The `?Sized` un-constraint is still needed for the trait object case, and still works since the value is always behind a pointer:

```
fn fbox(listener: &Box<dyn Listener>) {
    f(listener.as_ref());
}

fn fref<L>(listener: &L) where L: Listener {
    f(listener);
}

fn f<L>(_listener: &L)
where
    L: Listener + ?Sized
{
}
```

Comment: I think I finally understand what is the use of `?Sized`

Comment: is this mean `f` use dynamic dispatch ? Or as it's generic, the dynamic dispatch is only when `f` is used with `box` ?

Comment: @Stargateur It will use dynamic dispatch for the boxed trait object, but not for the known type. Remember that `f` will get monomorphised for each possible `T`.